# How to change font sizes companionabley in a document?

Tags: fontsize

I want to make the font size in a document generally as 14pt and have the font sizes for sectional divisions altered appropriately?

Comment: Which documentclass does your question refer to? Probably `\documentclass[14pt]{extreport}` is useful for you.

Answer (score 4):

In LaTeX the standard font sizes for a document are 10, 11 and 12pt. Internally fonts used may be larger or smaller. Overall the standard available font sizes are 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20 and 25pt; available through
macros like `\tiny` through `\Huge`.

To get a 14pt document size you can use the `extsizes` classes or package which provide document fonts of 8, 9, 10, 11 12, 14, 17 and 20pt. For instance

```
\documentclass[14pt]{extbook}
```

or

```
\documentclass{yourclass}
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
```

Alternatively you can use the `memoir` class (an extended version of the `book`, `report`, and `article` classes) which provides class font sizes of 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 17, 20, 25, 30, 36, 48 and 60pt.

```
\documentclass[14pt]{memoir}
```

(La)TeX follows, but does not replicate, the traditional (over 400 years) sequence of font sizes: 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 14, 16, 18, 21, 24, 36, 48, 60 and 72pt.

```
\usepackage[14pt]{extsizes}
```

The `tiny` etc. macros progress through the available font sizes; the range is slightly extended at the bottom and top in the `memoir` class which provides for a 14pt class size the following:

```
\miniscule    = 8pt
\tiny         = 9pt
\scriptsize   = 10pt
\footnotesize = 11pt
\small        = 12pt
\normalsize   = 14pt
\large        = 17pt
\Large        = 20pt 
\LARGE        = 25pt
\huge         = 30pt
\Huge         = 36pt
\HUGE         = 48pt
```

When you use `extsizes` or `memoir` the font sizes for sectional divisions are adjusted accordingly. For instance the default font for `\section` headings is `\Large\bfseries`, for `\subsection` headings is `\large\bfseries` and for `\subsubsection` headings is `\bfseries`. The `memoir` class provides facilities for easily changing these.

If you want to use non-LaTeX font sizes then you need infinitely adjustable fonts, which is another topic altogether.